# Django, How to create a text file when a link is clicked, save it on the server machine

Tags: django

I need to generate a text file from a Django-App when an admin user clicks on a link. I need the file to be saved on the **server machine NOT the user machine.**

How do I go about it?

Comment: I'm very to Django and this is the first application I'll be deploying. I have created a view which generates the data I need and when I click on the link I have created it downloads the file to the client machine not the server.

Comment: A hyperlink probably isn't the best way to invoke that function, unless you're planning on doing that via ajax, as they're really intended to navigate. Perhaps a button element would be best in this case. Any way, are you wanting to write this file, then redirect to another view?

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that. Anyway, I want to write to this file and save it to a specific location within the server.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data you want to write?

Comment: Brandon, thanks. I figured it out. I'll write the answer below.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

def myView(request):
    cdr = Cdr.objects.all()
    file_path = 'path/to/file/somefilename.csv'
    with open(file_path, 'w') as csvfile:
        file_header =['user', 'clid']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=file_hearder)
        for cd in cdr:
            writer.writerow({'user':'Extend=>'+ str(cd.user), 'clid':cd.clid})
    return HttpResponse('success')
```